# Replacing \begin{comment} and \end{comment} with macro, shorter spelled

Tags: macros, comments

I use the `comment` package and wish to replace the `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}`, together with format commands, with macro shorter spelled such as `\ans` et `\sna`.

I tried this :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0mm}


\newcommand{\ans}{\begin{detail}
\color{Plum}}
\newcommand{\sna}{
\end{detail}
\color{Black}}

\excludecomment{detail}
%\includecomment{detail}

Hello !\\
%\begin{detail}
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna
% \end{detail}
How are you ?

\end{document}
```

It fails. In fact, it is the `\sna` that makes it fail. `\ans` works, sort of : the Plum colour is ineffective except if I define \ans like that :

```
\newcommand{\ans}{\color{Plum}
\begin{detail}
}
```

I understand the problem is around the "The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it." stated in the documentation for the "comments" package. But I managed to work it around for `\ans` but not for `\sna`. I saw the questions [comment-package and macro definitions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332057/77011) and [A macro that processes and hides text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315835/77011) but didn't find the solution for my problem.

Is there a way to define `\sna` so that it does the job ?

Comment: hiding environments behind commands is a bad habit to get into, for verbatim like environments (as here) it doesn't work at all, also environments like ams alignments and some table environments.

Comment: @Ulrich Oups ! I edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\long\def\ansin#1\sna{\color{red}#1\color{black}}
\long\def\ansex#1\sna{}
\newcommand\excludecomment{\let\ans\ansex}
\newcommand\includecomment{\let\ans\ansin}
\excludecomment
\begin{document}
Hello!\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna
\includecomment
How are you?\\
Separate \ans lines are not \sna required.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: based on the same idea as Werner, ready to use ! I tried it in the real context and it works nicely ! Even "lighter" that to use a package. Great solution !!

Answer (score 5):

With environments defined via `\includecomment`/`\excludecomment`, the end of an instance of such an environment needs to be detected.

The detection-mechanism "assumes" that the phrase denoting the end of the environment can be derived by prepending to the name of the environment the phrase `\end{` and appending the phrase `}`.

The detection-mechanism does not trigger expansion of things for detecting that phrase but "expects" to find it *verbatim*.

Therefore with
      `\ans` → `\begin{detail}` and `\sna` → `\end{detail}`
you can, e.g., do
      `\excludecomment{detail}` ... `\ans` ... `\end{detail}`
, but you **cannot** do
      `\excludecomment{detail}` ... `\ans` ... `\sna`   :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ans}{\begin{detail}}
\newcommand{\sna}{\end{detail}}

\excludecomment{detail}
%\includecomment{detail}


Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\end{detail}
How are you ?

\end{document}
```

By the way:

`\excludecomment{detail}` ... `\begin{detail}` ... `\end⎵{detail}` (space between `\end` and `{detail}`) doesn't work either. It is not the same as `\end{detail}` (without space).

---

If you really absolutely want `\ans` ..`\sna` to work like `\begin{detail}`..`\end{detail}`, you can define a command `\ans` which saves the current color and hacks the commands `\Enddetailtest` and `\AfterdetailComment` (which are components of the `detail`-environment) in order to have the `detail`-environment scan for the phrase `\sna` instead of the phrase `\end{detail}`.  You need to be picky about the catcode-régime under which things get tokenized—therefore this is tricky.

You can do neither `\begin{detail}`.. `\sna` nor `\ans`..`\end{detail}`.

With `\ans`..`\sna` the same rules apply as with `\begin{detail}`..`\end{detail}`. E.g., `\sna` must be on a line of its own, not preceeded by spaces, ...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}

\setlength\parindent{0mm}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\^^M=12\relax%%%
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%%%
  \newcommand{\ans}{%
    \let\savedEnddetailTest=\EnddetailTest%%%
    \let\savedAfterdetailComment=\AfterdetailComment%%%
    \colorlet{savedcurrentcolor}{.}%
    {%
     \escapechar=-1\relax%%%
     \expandafter%%%
    }\expandafter\def\expandafter\EnddetailTest\expandafter{\string\\sna}%
    \toks@\expandafter{%
      \AfterdetailComment%%%
      \let\EnddetailTest=\savedEnddetailTest%%%
      \let\AfterdetailComment=\savedAfterdetailComment%%%
      \color{savedcurrentcolor}%
    }%
    \edef\AfterdetailComment{\the\toks@}%
    \begin{detail}^^M\color{Plum}%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\includecomment{detail}

Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna

Hello !\\
\begin{detail}
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\end{detail}

Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna

Hello !\\
\begin{detail}
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\end{detail}

\bigskip

\hrule

\bigskip

\excludecomment{detail}

Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna

Hello !\\
\begin{detail}
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\end{detail}

Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna

Hello !\\
\begin{detail}
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\end{detail}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With the example above with the `\ans`-command the catcode of the return-character (`^^M` in TeX's `^^`-notation) is changed to 12 in order to have the color-specification processed as if occurring on a new line.

Therefore with the `\ans`..`\sna`-command things are in the color `Plum` while with `\begin{detail}`..`\end{detail}` things are in the color `black`.

If you wish the color `Plum` both with `\ans`..`\sna` and with `\begin{detail}`..`\end{detail}`, you can omit this catcode-trickery and define the `detail`-environment in terms of `\specialcomment` instead of `\includecomment`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}

\setlength\parindent{0mm}

\newcommand{\ans}{%
  \let\savedEnddetailTest=\EnddetailTest
  \let\savedAfterdetailComment=\AfterdetailComment
  {%
   \escapechar=-1\relax
   \expandafter
  }\expandafter\def\expandafter\EnddetailTest\expandafter{\string\\sna}%
  \csname toks@\endcsname\expandafter{%
    \AfterdetailComment
    \let\EnddetailTest=\savedEnddetailTest
    \let\AfterdetailComment=\savedAfterdetailComment
  }%
  \edef\AfterdetailComment{\the\csname toks@\endcsname}%
  \begin{detail}%
}%

\begin{document}

\specialcomment{detail}%
               {\colorlet{savedcurrentcolor}{.}\color{Plum}}%
               {\color{savedcurrentcolor}}

Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna

Hello !\\
\begin{detail}
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\end{detail}

Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna

Hello !\\
\begin{detail}
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\end{detail}

\bigskip

\hrule

\bigskip

\excludecomment{detail}

Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna

Hello !\\
\begin{detail}
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\end{detail}

Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna

Hello !\\
\begin{detail}
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\end{detail}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To the question:

> *Is there a way to define \sna so that it does the job ?*

With the previous two examples the command `\sna` isn't defined at all. ;-)

---

---

When writing this answer and compiling/testing the code, according to the .log-file the following files/releases/versions were in use:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.1.17)  29 JAN 2021 23:13
LaTeX2e  patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
[...]
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
[...]
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
[...]
File: dvipsnam.def 2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
[...]
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-01-09 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
[...]
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
```

The .log-file only revealed the location of the file `comment.sty`, not the version.

Looking at the file at the denoted location revealed:

```
% Comment.sty   version 3.8, July 2016
% copyright 1998-2016 Victor Eijkhout
```

Comment: wow ! A complete study here !

Answer (score 2):

The best option for you here is to avoid the functionality of [`comment`](//ctan.org/pkg/comment) and use your own interface. To do this, you `\def`ine a `\long` version of `\ans` that captures everything up to `\sna`, after which you can do with it what you want. If you don't want to include anything between `\ans`...`\sna`, you can then just discard it. The example below provides both those options; keep both definitions and uncomment whichever you need:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% Similar to \includecomment for \ans...\sna
\long\def\ans#1\sna{{%
  \color{Plum}#1\ignorespaces%
}}
% Similar to \excludecomment for \ans...sna
%\long\def\ans#1\sna{\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0mm}

Hello !\\
\ans
I say hello because I have no better idea !\\
\sna
How are you ?

\end{document}
```

When you use the "gobble" version (second, similar to `\excludecomment`), the output resembles this:

[image]